# VBS RegRead doesn't return value

Tags: vbscript, registry

I've got the following code:

```
Dim objShell,failing_path,working_path

failing_path = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test"
working_path = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\7-zip\Path"

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Echo "Working: " & objShell.RegRead(working_path) 
WScript.Echo "Not Working: " & objShell.RegRead(failing_path)
```

When executing I will get the Path from the `7-zip Registrykey`, but the `Test` Key returns following error:

[image]

Error says: **Registry wasn't opened for reading.**

Here the proof that the Test-Key exists:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I also tried to read the key via `oReg.GetStringValue` but this always returned null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your script is running in a 32-Bit compatible scripting host but in a 64-bit OS.
Since 32 bit applications are automatically redirected to the `WOW6432Node` areas of the registry in 64-Bit OSes, `RegRead` method tries to read 32-Bit equivalent path like

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test`

instead

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Test`

So, if the redirected path does not exist you receive that error as expected.

You may need to force run your scripts in 64-bit compatible scripting hosts to get rid of that kind of implicit registry redirects.

Comment: allright i understand that, i will try it out tomorrow, but i cant run the script in 64-Bit mode, and i need the values from both(32 and 64 bit) paths, because there are different entries. Is there a way to acces the 64 bit area out of 32 bit script? (btw. i will upvode you post as well as soon as my daily vote limit runned of ;) )

Comment: @Recall Yes there is but more painful :) Have a look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I tested this, I was able to read from non-Wow6432Node paths just fine, even when using a 32-bit `cscript.exe` from a 32-bit `cmd.exe` (Process Explorer showed image type 32-bit for both processes).

Perhaps it's something really simple? I was able to reproduce the behavior you described when I created a registry value with a spurious trailing space:

```
>>> key = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
>>> WScript.Echo sh.RegRead(key & "Test")
Unable to open registry key "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
Uninstall\Test" for reading. (0x80070002)
>>> WScript.Echo sh.RegRead(key & "Test ")
asd
```

Comment: it's interessting, i startet the 32 bit cmd and run the script i got two times the 32 Bit Key, with the Wow6432Node and the normal path. The problem is my script will be called later from an 32 bit programm, running on a 64 bit OS so i guess it will be difficult to get to the 64 bit keys